# How to open a view form server site and display its link in Asp.net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, hyperlink, server-side

I wrote a Web Application. In which the users can make inputs which will be saved 
in a database. (with a [HttpPost] function). From these functions I open other Views. My problm is that althought the Views show up without any problem the path in the link stays the same. This is problematic when I want to go back or I want to copy the link... My idea was to somehow display the link per javascript everytime I load a View but that seems to be a very unprofessional way of doing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple,

```
<div class="table-outer">
    <table width="50%" align="center" border="1">
        <tr>
            <td>Column1</td>
            <td>Column2</td>
            <td>Column3</td>
            <td>Column4</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

</div>

.table-outer{width:100%; background:#ddd;padding:20px}
```

automatically align center

https://jsfiddle.net/kamatchikumar/3u5qwqms/